# Kaminari installed but apparently not seen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

A rails test is generating an error as follows

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `total_pages' for nil:NilClass

        options[:total_pages] ||= scope.total_pages
```

for this specific line in the view:    `<%= paginate @carts %>` 
The controller action  generates an empty array according to the following logic

```
    if user?
      @carts = Cart.order(created_at: :desc).where([user_id = ?, current_user.id]).page params[:page]
    else
      @carts = []
    end
```

Kaminari is bundled

```
Using kaminari-core 1.2.2
Using kaminari-actionview 1.2.2
Using kaminari-activerecord 1.2.2
Using kaminari 1.2.2
```

a `puts @carts.size` does show `0` in the logging. so the array object exists but the scoping is not activating.
It appears the base settings of kaminari are not kicking in in this particular instance, whereas in another case  `@users = User.page params[:page]` the test does not complain.

How does this get resolved?

Answer (score 1):

```rb
paginate []     # undefined method `total_pages' for []:Array
paginate nil    # undefined method `total_pages' for nil:NilClass
#        ^                                           ^
# NOTE: from the error it looks like @carts is nil --'
```

`kaminari` needs an *ActiveRecord* class or relation object and `page` method has to be called on that class/object for it to [become](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/blob/v1.2.2/kaminari-activerecord/lib/kaminari/activerecord/active_record_model_extension.rb#L15-L19) "paginatable" and for scoping to kick in:

```rb
paginate Cart             # => undefined method `total_pages' for Cart:Class
paginate Cart.all         # => undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Rel...

paginate Cart.page(1)     # => <nav class="pagination" ...
paginate Cart.all.page(1) # => <nav class="pagination" ...
```

*Kaminari* has a helper to paginate over an array:

```rb
@array = Kaminari.paginate_array([1,2,3]).page(1).per(10)

paginate @array           # => <nav class="pagination" ...
```

An empty *Cart* relation object can also be used:

```rb
paginate Cart.none.page   # => ""
```

---

*https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object*